# Marvel Ultimate Alliance 1 Extreme Power Order

Tags: marvel-ultimate-alliance

In Marvel Ultimate Alliance 1, when one member of the team activates his 'extreme' power all other team members with their extreme gauge filled also activate their specials.  When playing multi-player with friends, how is the order the extremes are executed in determined?

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you are asking. When you are playing with your friends don't you decide on things like this in-game? I haven't played multiplayer for MUA but have done the sp.

Answer (score 1):

I think when playing in multiplayer, as far as I can remember when I played it a long time ago, each player could trigger their extremes separately.